# Send javascript arrays via ajax without using jquery

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, ajax

i have a javascript array with values like "correct", "wrong".
I want to send this array to my php file using ajax. But im not familiar with how. 
This is what i have tried so far..and i would like to do this without jquery.

```
var hold=[];
    for(t = 0;t <= 10; t++){ 
    answers_Arr = document.getElementsByName("question"+t);
    for (k = 0; k < answers_Arr.length; k++){
        if(answers_Arr[k].checked){
            hold[t] = answers_Arr[k].value;
            //document.getElementById("test"+t).innerHTML = "Value: "+ hold[t];
            break;
        }else{
            hold[t] = "no";
            continue;

        }
    }
}
var jsonString = JSON.stringify(hold);
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function()
{
    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4  &&  xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    document.getElementById("test1").innerHTML= xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
}

xmlhttp.open("GET","result.php?res="+hold[],true);
xmlhttp.send();

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example of sending the json string with POST through AJAX:

```
var jsonString = JSON.stringify(hold);
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    //
}

xmlhttp.open("POST","result.php",true);
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
xmlhttp.send(jsonString);
```

Avoid sending json strings with GET method because if the request string gets too long, the browser will throw you an error.

Now in your php script you will have all the data in $_POST

Edit: Looks like on some versions of php, the requests that have other `Content-type`, like `application/json`, the $_POST has an empty value. To fix this you can do:

```
$_POST = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'));
```

Comment: Thank you. Can u help me with the php script for retrieving this too?

Comment: You should have all the data in $_POST like you would send it through a normal form. If you are unsure what the variable contains, you can always print the contents of it with `print_r($_POST);`

Comment: i tried using print_r($_POST); but it only prints 'array()'. Thats  it.

Comment: I am curious what version of php are you using? Can you also try this: `$_POST = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'));`

Comment: `<?php
include 'Connect.php';
$myarray= $_POST;
print_r($_POST);` **This is what i tried**

Comment: Try to update your code like so: `<?php include 'Connect.php'; $_POST = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input')); $myarray = $_POST; print_r($_POST);`

Comment: Good to know. I've updated the response in case someone else has this problem.

Answer (score 0):

replace this line

```
xmlhttp.open("GET","result.php?res="+hold[],true);
```

with

```
xmlhttp.open("GET","result.php?res="+jsonString,true);
```

Comment: it still says undefined for 'res'. And also when i display the array in php., it displays null

Comment: you mean you are getting undefined in your php script?

Comment: This is what i used in my php script,**'$res = json_decode(stripslashes($_GET['res']));
echo json_encode($res);'**